# How to load a specific Topojson with Vega

Tags: vega

I am new to Vega and I would like to load this topojson with Vega :

https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/blob/master/countries/france/fr-departments.json

I have already followed the airport tutorial but I dont know what to write in the "projections" and "format" field to insert my topojson.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response but posting as it could be useful for others.

Here are the key attributes/changes for the map to work:

- `"feature": "FRA_adm2"` in `data[0].format`. I picked this from the [topojson](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/countries/france/fr-departments.json)'s `objects` key
- `"field": "properties.ID_1"`. Important for `scale`, `legend`, map `fill`. I picked this from the topojson's `objects.FRA_adm2.geometries[0].properties`, assuming that's the unique sub-region key.
- define a `projection` and use it the mark's `transform` attribute

```
...
"data": [{
  "name": "table",
  "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/countries/france/fr-departments.json",
  "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "FRA_adm2"}
}],

...
"projections": [{
  "name": "projection",
  "size": {"signal": "[width, height]"},
  "fit": {"signal": "data('table')"},
  "type": "mercator"
}],
...

"marks": [{
  ...
  "transform": [{"type": "geoshape", "projection": "projection"}]
}]
...
```

### specification

Vega specification: [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhA4kAE3k1xZNAJkB3GvPpoALAAYDM+DTJY0AZiMz5STClQBtUOKQI4aEA6YAbTzIMAE6+Xli4+ERBSBrUdIxMDBBwQVASmHDimJRpCATycL4FQRCkRQSYbDhsohIEyBAZQQRpDFlBNHAQBABm0eJQcL1BALQFckGYHlkQImKSMj1sQciYaKCYAJ44nuiV1bULID1w9sG7IABiAEoAggD6CggATCAAvm8AujI4QTVwUEw7HEEDQLhAbg8Xl+-0BwOkIAgNAAXrtQEiyG5QugnFodDApAACUzmTCfd6LOjrRFmLFeOwOAAUAHIfP5mQBKCnebYXDypezLd7fRFQJD+UHOVzuC5pXxCmRbHZeACODCQWRRARA8jYyGU1IZjm8SD82p6nSK0L+O0mnVmAEl5Nz+mQ0aLuLsnCAAMQAEWel2eAFEAEIIn0ARj9AGEDABOW4gEWtLL6D4i-xu8TySXgi2+bEgOUKkDLTpp9BMNjYPUIpRBAFAiRhcvI9Li4UyZBBADWeelUPQviQmxS9wM9x7-YRSouEBgSGViz+CEN9mNbM8bxkmTSBWpDBwDPdBex6LF-i8JaCCIthWd6BhtqBXUoDr990j3Maf177uIcUGAuDQYDobcZCQDokGuNh-D9LooA6HBm0kVBQEA3xgK8N02AXJcIO8Ng4KBHBqQxOl0AZBgEEoZ8UlfUEPh3bx+ggJYVjBDZeRwuA8MXZdZD+YQm3hJ9hNElsvmkoA)